# Is it possible to extract the relation between the flow of time and the density of space from GTR?

Tags: general-relativity, time, time-dilation, observers, density

Is it even possible to formulate such relation?

Comment: What you mean with "density of space"?

Comment: There is gravitational time dilation. In analogy, I think of gravitational length contraction.

Comment: To understand you properly, can define the meaning "flow of time"?

Comment: I mean the pace of flow of time, that is slower on the surface of the planet in comparison to the intergalactic space.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. If you don't mind I will try to explain it clearly tomorrow. In the meantime I wish you a Happy New Year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gravitational time dilation and length contraction are analogues to that in special relativity theory (SR). For example, in static spherically spacetime the first one is related to square root of metric component $g_{00}$ and the second, to square root of metric component $g_{rr}$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
d\tau=\sqrt{g_{00}}~dt<dt,~~~~~dl=\sqrt{g_{rr}}~dr>dr~.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
In particular, for Schwarzschild vacuum metric, it yields
\begin{equation}
d\tau=\sqrt{1-r_{S}/r}\cdot dt<dt,~~~~~dl=1/\sqrt{1-r_{S}/r}\cdot dr>dr,\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $\tau$ is called proper time, and $l$ proper distance or length.
A very lucid explanation of the connection between $\gamma$ factor in SR and metric factors in GR one can find on page 4 in S. M. Blinder's paper "Centennial of General Relativity (1915-2015); The Schwarzschild Solution and Black Holes", https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02061 .

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation and the Blinder's paper. Is it a heresy to multiply the last two equations by sides to shorten the gamma factor and interpret the result? If not, how would you interpret it?

Comment: @Marcin, no it is not a heresy. In SR its meaning is just that length contraction can be derived from time dilation (see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction, section Using time dilation). Generally, in SR and GR time dilation means always length contraction.

Comment: I get it and I agree, so I'm asking directly - is this correct?
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/685237/is-the-flow-of-time-inversely-proportional-to-the-density-of-space

Comment: @safesphere Thank you, very helpful. Maybe you know if there is a justified postulate of the elementary and quantized spacetime volume?

Comment: @safesphere, thanks a lot for your corrections!